# Disappointment to/at/in see(ing)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

When I have a construction like this:

> He expressed his disappointment, regret, joy, amazement **to/at/in see(ing)** that something had happened.

What is the correct preposition and form of the verb "to see"? Is it **to see**, **at seeing**, **in seeing**, etc.?

Comment: You can leave the preposition out. "He expressed his disappointment, regret, joy, *and* amazement seeing that something had happened."

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the noun:

- He expressed his disappointment in seeing that something had
  happened.
- He expressed his regret of seeing that something had
  happened.
- He expressed his joy in seeing that something had happened.
- He expressed his amazement at seeing that something had happened.

Although I would recommend:

- He was disappointed/overjoyed/amazed to see that something had happened.